# Error while building PJSIP with FFMPEG storage size of 'dstFormat' isn't known

Tags: android, gcc, ffmpeg, pjsip, pjsua2

**Building PJSIP for armeabi with FFMPEG gives me following output:**

```
../src/pjmedia/converter_libswscale.c: In function 'factory_create_converter':
../src/pjmedia/converter_libswscale.c:70:24: error: storage size of 'srcFormat' isn't known
 enum AVPixelFormat srcFormat, dstFormat;
                    ^
```

I've read many articles about problems with PixelFormat -> AVPixelFormat in newer versions of FFMPEG(Such as one i've built for PJSIP) - I got all of my pj sources updated according with AVPixelFormat.

**Building environment:**

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64bit running in VirtualBox

PJSIP 2.6

FFMPEG 3.0.9

**Compiling PJSIP with flags:**

#define PJMEDIA_HAS_VIDEO 1

#define PJMEDIA_HAS_FFMPEG 1

**NDK-flag:**

--with-ffmpeg="${BASE_DIR}/ffmpeg-output"

**ffmpeg-output folder contains these files:**

- libavcodec.so
- libavcodec.so.57
- libavcodec.so.57.24.102
- libavdevice.so
- libavdevice.so.57
- libavdevice.so.57.0.101
- libavfilter.so
- libavfilter.so.6
- libavfilter.so.6.31.100
- libavformat.so
- libavformat.so.57
- libavformat.so.57.25.100
- libavutil.so
- libavutil.so.55
- libavutil.so.55.17.103
- libpostproc.so
- libpostproc.so.54
- libpostproc.so.54.0.100
- libswresample.so
- libswresample.so.2
- libswresample.so.2.0.101
- libswscale.so
- libswscale.so.4
- libswscale.so.4.0.100

Trying to build different versions of FFMPEG didn't work at all(Got the same error at the end)

Any help will be appreciated.

**UPD**:
Is there any strange stuff aboud AVPixelFormat in this part of compiler output related to ffmpeg:

```
checking ffmpeg packages...  libavdevice libavformat libavcodec libswscale libavutil
checking for enum AVPixelFormat... no
checking for v4l2_open in -lv4l2... no
Checking if OpenH264 is disabled... yes
Skipping Intel IPP settings (not wanted)
```

I mean the line says "checking for enum AVPixelFormat... no" - is there any flag I need to write to say to PJSIP "you have to work with AVPixelFormat"?

Comment: did you add this code (enum AVPixelFormat srcFormat, dstFormat;) or   predeclared in converter_libwscale.c?

Comment: @NandhaKumar I didn't make any changes in converter_libwscale.c

Comment: "checking for enum AVPixelFormat... no" it need to return yes. check how to add AVPixelFormat source code into pjsip.

Comment: @NandhaKumar I've found some check in avconfigure file related to AVPixelFormat. It makes some sort of check(ac_fn_c_check_type "$LINENO" "enum AVPixelFormat" "ac_cv_type_enum_AVPixelFormat" "#include <libavformat/avformat.h>) and decides what to use, based on check result. I've found implementation of that function in that file, trying to understand, what it's doing. I'm not good at that type of code, maybe you can help me understand what this thing does?

Comment: according to line( if eval \${$3+:} false; then :) of function I mentioned above (it's returning false, I checked it), seems like this script can't find variable called "ac_cv_type_enum_AVPixelFormat" in somewhere.

Comment: I've changed base ffmpeg project, I've now stuck with another error (ffmpeg_vid_codecs.c:1437: error: undefined reference to 'av_frame_unref')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved compiling PJSIP + FFMPEG based on another project from scratch

Comment: can you share your build script? I have the same error while building the pjsip with ffmpeg+libx264.

Comment: @Meonardo Unfortunately, I can't. But we're using slightly adjusted version of build script from VoiSmart, maybe that source can help you: https://github.com/VoiSmart/pjsip-android-builder